# Java Swing versus dot-net for Standlaone applications

Tags: java, .net, swing

How does Java Swing compare against dot-net in terms of developing Standalone application interacting with database and a messaging service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I prefer Java for everything because it can be run on any device. Most (all) of the .NETs only run on windows. It really depends on what you are trying to create...

Best of luck!

Comment: There are always Pros and Cons related to every language, though +1 for the big DIFFERENCE :-)

Comment: If you are development a desktop application for the average user .NET is far superior. If you are developing an open source desktop application Java would be more accepted. Most average users run Windows and .NET integrates with Windows significantly better than Java.

Comment: @ChristonianCoder : You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)